# Cannot register the hard disk VBox. Why and how to solve?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm trying to clone a VBox Machine, But getting the below error.
But it does not give error with other source file.

```
IMedium medium = sVirtualBox.OpenMedium(oldMediumPath,
DeviceType.DeviceType_HardDisk, AccessMode.AccessMode_ReadOnly, 0);
```

Exception:

```
{"Cannot register the hard disk 'C:\\Code\\Data.vdi.backup' {e99dab6a-1e34-4579-ae6b-4a7e520933c6} because a hard disk 'C:\\Code\\hd\\Data.vdi' with UUID {e99dab6a-1e34-4579-ae6b-4a7e520933c6} already exists"}
```

Comment: This isn't a C# specific question. In fact, the solution probably doesn't relate to the .NET stack at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and [this solution from the VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=64411) worked for me: delete the VirtualBox.xml file (or rename it to VirtualBox.xml_YYYYMMDD). On my ubuntu host, this file lives in `$HOME/.VirtualBox/`

When I restarted the VirtualBox GUI, I just had to do Machine-->Add to add all my virtual machines back in.